# Ball not coming back after colliding in p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, web, p5.js

```js
var x, y, speed, speed2, speedx, speedy;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1200, 630);
    x = 50;
    y = 300;

    speed = 20;
    speed2 = 20;

    speedx = createSlider(2, 50, 20);
    speedx.position(1000, 100);
    speedx.style('width', '200px');

    speedy = createSlider(10, 50, 20);
    speedy.position(1000, 150);
    speedy.style('width', '200px');
}

function draw() {
    background("white");

    x = x + speedx.value();
    y = y + speedy.value();
    if (x > 1170) {
        x = x - speedx.value();
    }
    if (x < 10) {
        x = x + speedx.value();
    }
    if (y > 610) {
        y = y - speedy.value();
    }
    if (y < 15) {
        x = x + speedx.value();
    }
    let color1 = color("black");
    fill(color1);
    ellipse(x, y, 20);
}
```

**
I am new to p5.js and made this (my first code) but it is not working as I expected

Please help me by answering this code
**

Comment: Please add details. What do you expect to happen, what does happen, and what is your precise question? Thanks. That said, you probably need additional variables: `speedX` and `speedY` rather than hardcoded numbers. Multiply these vars by `-1` when you hit a wall to change direction, taking care to resolve the collision by moving the ball out of the wall before the next frame.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code isn't going to make the ball "come back" because while it is limiting the x and y positions, it doesn't change the x and y velocities (so once the ball gets to the edge it is just going to stick there). You also have a few defects in to edge limiting logic.

1. Your sliders are always positive so the ball can only move down and to the right.
2. When you check the y position against the minimum you modify the x position instead of the y position.
3. When you check the x position against the minimum value you are adding the speeds, but presumably when this happens speed would be negative (i.e. moving to the left), so you still want to subtract.

```js
var x, y, speedx, speedy;

function setup() {
  // make the canvas cover the window
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  x = width / 2;
  y = height / 2;

  // create slider ranges such that things don't always go down and to the right
  speedx = createSlider(-10, 10, 2);
  speedx.position(10, 10);
  speedx.style("width", "200px");

  speedy = createSlider(-10, 10, 2);
  speedy.position(10, 50);
  speedy.style("width", "200px");
}

function draw() {
  background("white");

  x = x + speedx.value();
  y = y + speedy.value();
  if (x > width - 10) {
    x = x - speedx.value();
  }
  if (x < 10) {
    // presumably the reason we're going off the screen is that speedx is negative.
    x = x - speedx.value();
  }
  if (y > height - 10) {
    y = y - speedy.value();
  }
  if (y < 10) {
    y = y - speedy.value();
  }
  let color1 = color("black");
  fill(color1);
  ellipse(x, y, 20);
}
```

```css
html, body {margin:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (visit codecademy for details: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-p5js/lessons/p5js-animation)

```
     speedx *= -1
```

You can do the same thing with `speedy`